# Write Activity to .vmem file even though the VM is suspended

Tags: hard-drive, performance, vmware

I have a VMWare VM I have to use for certain tasks at work. For some reason while the VM is running *or* suspended something is doing massive (in terms of operations, not Bytes/s) I/O on its `.vmem` file, making the system on that disk very sluggish.

Resource Monitor basically shows the culprit of the performance problems:

[image]

And the top spot in Disk Activity is always taken by the System process accessing said file.

[image]

Anyone knows what's going on here?

Comment: delayed writes?

Comment: Half an hour after the VM was suspended? In packets of roughly 1 MiB/s?

Comment: just guessing, maybe VMWare's scheduling writes when idle or the like. Curious to know the real reason too

Comment: I just tried whether it's the same after a restart, but got a Bluescreen when resuming the VM ... trying again now ;-)

Comment: Bit of background here on the suspended aspect. When you suspend a VM, it's RAM is written to the VMEM file. Watch resource monitor and you'll see a big block go from green (in use) to orange (modified) when you suspend the VM. Windows then flushes the modified blocks to the VMEM file. This flushing really hammers a SATA-3 drive causing a very unresponsive system. Second the modified memory hits zero, performance returns

Comment: The VMEM activity seems to have got a lot worse on WS11 on Windows 8.1 - I can have just one 3GB VM running on a 16GB host PC and periodically some processes on the host lock up - always VMware workstation itself and sometimes anything else trying to access the same disk where the VMEM file is stored. Interestingly, like the original poster here, bytes/second write is usually relatively low but there are a lot of operations. So the queue length hits the roof but the throughput is nowhere near the raw speed of SATA-3 drives (let's say 80MB/s)

Answer (score 12):

According to vmware forums you need to have this setting in your config.ini:
mainmem.useNamedFile = "FALSE" to avoid this problem. VMWare would use the real RAM and page file with this setting turned false.

References:

1. http://communities.vmware.com/message/1704684
2. http://vmfaq.com/entry/25/
3. http://faq.sanbarrow.com/index.php?action=artikel&cat=14&id=50&artlang=en

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a fix - this problem appears to have got a lot worse in WS v11 on Windows 8.1. Suspect changes in memory management